# How to give range for nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3.

I have some upstream nodes and some downstream nodes. How can i give a range for the tick function so that each time the nodes get formed , they are withing the same range.
Because each time you run, the distance between the nodes keep varying. Is there a way to give a range ? so that the nodes always remain aligned in the center i.e. above and below the center node?

the distance between the nodes should stay fixed and they should be aligned properly on the top and bottom. i.e. nearby half nodes to the left and almost half nodes to the right?

Below is the link for the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/k2NL5/86/

```
node.attr("cx", function (d) {


            return d.x;
    })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
         for(var counter=0;counter<fromlength;counter++)
      if(from_projects[counter]==d.id)
          return 100;

        for(var counter=0;counter<tolength;counter++)
      if(to_projects[counter]==d.id)
          return 200;   

        return 150;


    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the force layout doesn't support this.

Comment: Can i give a left and right margin kind of thing so that the nodes get placed in that particular range?

Comment: No. The force layout doesn't support any such additional constraints on the layout. You would need to enforce them yourself in the `tick` handler function.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way to do that. My "y" is fixed . I want to manipulate my "x" attribute of node.

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is whether you need the force layout. If you simply want to distribute the nodes across a certain width, you don't.